# ORDER BY an equal value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

All,
I've got the following SQL query as of now:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id=$wpdb->posts.ID
JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id=$wpdb->posts.ID
WHERE 
$wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
AND $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id='$vendor_category_to_use'
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key='zip'
```

I have a `postmeta.meta_key` called `featured`. Then the value of if the post is featured is in another column called `postmeta.meta_value`. If the `meta_value = "yes"` where the meta_key equals "featured" then I want to display this one first and then display the rest of the posts after that. How can I go about doing that?

EDIT: Here is the data setup:

```
postid       meta_key      meta_value
123          featured      yes
324          featured      no
182          featured      yes
873          featured      yes
```

So in this example I'd like my posts to be displayed in this order:

```
postid       meta_key      meta_value
123          featured      yes
182          featured      yes
873          featured      yes
324          featured      no
```

I hope that helps!

Here is the SQL that gets generated:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts 
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id=wp_posts.ID 
JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id=wp_posts.ID 
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id='5' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='zip' AND (wp_postmeta.meta_value = '46320' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value = '46321' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value = '46322' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value = '46323' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value = '46324' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value = '46327' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value = '46394' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value = '46402' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value = '46404' ) 
ORDER BY (wp_postmeta.meta_key='featured' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value='yes') DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM   ...
ORDER BY (meta_key='featured' AND meta_value='yes') DESC, postid ASC;
```

If `(meta_key='featured' AND meta_value='yes')` for a row, that row will have a 1/TRUE. Otherwise, it will have a 0/FALSE. Hence, sorting descending puts the rows that have TRUE first.

Comment: I updated my question again with the SQL that is being produced. For some reason it isn't sorting them by the featured. I think because it's selecting records based on my zip code instead of selecting all of the records and then doing the sort. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your SQL looks fine, and the sql I gave also works -- when I do `CREATE TABLE foo (id INT, meta_key VARCHAR(10), meta_value VARCHAR(10));` and `INSERT INTO foo VALUES (123,'featured','yes'),(324,'featured','no'),(182,'featured','yes'),(873,'featured','yes');` (the data you gave in your question), and apply a `SELECT *` with the `ORDER BY` in my answer, it gives the desired output.

Comment: As an aside, you are only selecting rows satisfying `WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key='zip'`, so you can't sort on `wp_postmeta.meta_key='featured'` because there aren't any - I think this is what you were trying to say?

Comment: You're correct I just figured it out and was going to post back here. I needed to add another OR statement to also select the featured variables. It is working now. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward like this:

```
...
ORDER BY featured = 'yes'
```

`featured = 'yes'` is evaluates as boolean true or false, for items that `featured = "yes"` is true will come first then items that has `featured = "yes"` is false i.e `featured = "no"` come later.

### Update:

You can use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement in the `order by` clause to sort your data on a sepecific field, something like:

```
ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN postmeta.meta_key = 'featured' 
             THEN meta_value = 'yes' DESC  
        END
```

**OR:**

```
ORDER BY ( postmeta.meta_key = 'featured' AND meta_value = 'yes') DESC
```

You might need to add another order by criteria in the `ELSE` part of the `CASE` statement to order the items that have `meta_key = 'featured` is false to order them by.

If the field `metadata_key` is always `= "featured"` then you can get rid of the case statement and use just `ORDER BY meta_value = 'yes' DESC`

Comment: Thanks I updated my question a little bit. I don't think I asked it correctly. This is the update: I have a postmeta.meta_key called featured. Then the value of if the post is featured is in another column called postmeta.meta_value. If the meta_value="yes" where the meta_key equals "featured" then I want to display this one first and then display the rest of the posts after that. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Can there be an AND clause in there? Let me update my question with some data to hopefully give you a better understanding of the DB structure.

Comment: @user1048676, you can add `AND` clause, but you didn't need it, becouse the `CASE` statement will first ensure that `meta_key = featured`. Or you can remove the case and add it in the `AND` condition

Comment: I updated my question again with the SQL that is being produced. For some reason it isn't sorting them by the featured. I think because it's selecting records based on my zip code instead of selecting all of the records and then doing the sort. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user1048676, **BTW:** you can use `where wp_postmeta.meta_value in ('value1', 'value2', ..)` instead of these `OR`'s.

Comment: I added the data it was returning. I wasn't sure how to format it. I have no idea why it isn't being sorted correctly. It looks right to me...

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use MySQL function named

```
FIELD(HAYSTACK, value[, ...values]).
```

This function returns index of haystack in values (FROM 1 to n, 0 - if not found).

**Example**

```
ORDER BY FIELD(wp_postmeta.meta_key, 'featured', wp_postmeta.meta_key), 
FIELD(wp_postmeta.meta_value, 'yes', wp_postmeta.meta_value), wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

But, in your case, use the mathematical.coffee example. In my example you need to repeat the field name in the end of list, because if you don't - it will return 0 (zero) and elements than not in list will be first in result statement.