# Rails 4 ActiveRecord Query: bind variables in order clause

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm attempting to have a dynamic order built into my mysql query so that certain matches are prioritized at the top.

```
Ticket.where(
  "id LIKE :search || name LIKE :search", 
  {search: "%#{params[:search]}]%"}
).order(
  "id = :exact DESC, name = :exact DESC, id LIKE :search DESC, name LIKE :search DESC", 
  {exact: params[:search], search: "%#{params[:search]}%"}
)
```

The query should end up like this assuming params[:search] = 'search_value':

```
SELECT * FROM tickets
WHERE id LIKE "%search_value%" || name LIKE "%search_value%"
ORDER BY id = 'search_value' DESC, name = 'search_value' DESC, id LIKE "%search_value%" DESC, name LIKE "%search_value%" DESC;
```

Anytime I do this however I get an error from ActiveRecord::QueryMethods.validate_order_args saying Direction should be :asc or :desc.

With the exception of manually sanitizing the search and then interpolating it directly into the order string, is there a way to get this to function like the where clause's bind variables?

Comment: Your "order by" part is not correct. "order by" can't include equal signs! It just doesn't make sense to put the search_value into the "order by" part. See the MySQL reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: That is absolutely incorrect, the equals will return 1 or 0.  So depending on how the search evaluates the end result is executed as "ORDER BY 1 DESC, 0 DESC, 1 DESC, 0 DESC" on a per record basis.  Just try doing "select * from anything order by 10 = id DESC" it will return id 10 at the top, followed by everything else.

Comment: Okay, i didn't know until now. Thank you for this hint. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9405844/4375900)

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging I think I've found a solution to this, although I wish rails had a better way.

I've included this in my rails project

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.corder *array
    statement = array.shift
    while (i=array.shift).present?
      case i
      when Hash
        i.each do |k,v|
          statement.gsub!(':' + k.to_s, ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(v))
        end
      when String
        statement.sub!('?', ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(i))
      else
        raise "Unknown type: #{i} -- #{i.class}"
      end
    end
    self.order(statement)
  end

  def corder *array
    statement = array.shift
    while (i=array.shift).present?
      case i
      when Hash
        i.each do |k,v|
          statement.gsub!(':' + k.to_s, sanitize(v))
        end
      when String
        statement.sub!('?', sanitize(i))
      else
        raise "Unknown type: #{i} -- #{i.class}"
      end
    end
    self.order!(statement)
  end
end
```

For my purposes this works perfectly although it could easily be expanded.  The two are exact duplicates (simple solution to needing it on the class and instance).

At this point you can:

```
Model.where(
  'id LIKE :search || name LIKE :search', 
  {search: "%#{params[:search]}%"}
).order(
  'id = :exact DESC, name = :exact DESC, id LIKE :rough DESC, name LIKE :rough DESC', 
  {exact: params[:search], rough: "%#{params[:search]}%"}
)
```

SQL assuming params[:search] == 'ibm':

```
SELECT * FROM model WHERE id LIKE '%ibm%' || name LIKE '%ibm%' ORDER BY id = 'ibm' DESC, name = 'ibm' DESC, id LIKE '%ibm%' DESC, name LIKE '%ibm%' DESC;
```

Alternatively the '?' bind variables work as well, eg:

```
Model.where(
  'id LIKE ? || name LIKE ?', 
  "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%"
).order(
  'id = ? DESC, name = ? DESC, id LIKE ? DESC, name LIKE ? DESC', 
  params[:search], params[:search], "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%"
)
```